# Pointers and Variables in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, variables, pointers

```
NSString *testString;  
testString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

I do not understand this no matter how many answers I read about it - people keep on interchanging terms, saying that testString is a variable, then saying that is a pointer and I am quite confused.

Here is my understanding so far. We declare the pointer testString in the first line... then does [[NSString alloc] init] return an actual NSString object or the address of an NSString object?

Comment: It may help to know that something can be *both* a variable and a pointer. A pointer is a kind of variable.

Comment: @GregHewgill That is, until it is a const pointer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example `testString` is a variable of type "pointer to `NSString`".

All Objective C objects are handled through fields and variables of pointer type. When they say "`init` returns an object", an expanded version of this statement should be "`init` returns a pointer to an object". However, since all objects are dealt with through pointers, the "pointer to" clarification can be safely dropped.

Comment: I'm finding conversations with people who "safely drop the 'pointer to' qualification" rather tiring :-S

Comment: Is a variable of type pointer different than an actual pointer and why?

Comment: Would an "actual" pointer, then, be a memory address? Does this apply in C as well? ( int *number creates a variable of type pointer to an int)

Comment: Can you show me a case where we dereference a pointer to a non objwct?

Answer (score 0):

It returns the address of an NSString.

Like many Object Oriented languages, Obj-C uses *references* (a.k.a., pointers) to Objects.

```
NSString *testString;
```

merely creates a local variable testString that is undefined at the moment but will soon contain a reference to an NSString object.

```
testString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

causes the runtime system to allocate an NSString object somewhere in memory, and returns a pointer to that location in memory. The '=' operator assigns that memory address to the variable testString.

Your observation is correct about interchanging terms. In practice we tend to think of testString as if it were the string itself, but it really is a pointer to wherever-it-happened-to-get-allocated.

For the record - this is true for all Objects, not just strings. When we alloc an object a reference to the new Object is returned.